# Multiple endpoints with the same path but with different @RequestParam values

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, http-request-parameters

I have an API path `GET /users/copy`. I can have two APIs with the same `/users/type` path but with different sets of RequestParams using the following construction:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/users/copy", params = {"type"})
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> copyUserWithType(@RequestParam UserTypeEnum type) {
    ...
}

@GetMapping(value = "/users/copy", params = {"origin"})
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> copyUserWithOrigin(@RequestParam UserOriginEnum origin) {
    ...
}
```

**BUT** in case I need to have different APIs for different user types (like for `type = OLD` and `type = NEW`), is there a way to still have the same `GET /users/copy` path for them?

Perhaps something like:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/users/copy", params = {"type=OLD"})
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> copyUserWithTypeOld(@RequestParam UserTypeEnum type) {
    ...
}  

@GetMapping(value = "/users/copy", params = {"type=NEW"})
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> copyUserWithTypeNew(@RequestParam UserTypeEnum type) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't know  why you want to do this, but this is not a good pattern. You can do if else inside method. Still you want to use, you can do `/users/copy/type/old` `/users/copy/type/new`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that my question is peculiar. But adding suffixes is not an option for me

Comment: If you want fixed param then you use  suffix is better. Or use if-else inside method.

Comment: I can't add suffixes and I'd very much like to avoid additional if-else constructions. Otherwise I wouldn't have had this question

Comment: If you are taking request param and doing static behavior then there is no meaning to use request param actually. And if you want to filter User using userType  you can query  dynamically in the repository  (guessing data fetching)

Comment: It makes sense. But the question remains, at least out of the sporting interest

Comment: Did you _try_ this?

Comment: My goodness! I never thought something that trivial would work! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the answer was in the question.

In order to have different APIs endpoints with the same path and the same set of @RequestParam, but with different @RequestParam values you need to specify `params` attribute as such:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/users/copy", params = {"type=OLD"})
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> copyUserWithTypeOld(@RequestParam UserTypeEnum type) {
    ...
}  

@GetMapping(value = "/users/copy", params = {"type=NEW"})
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> copyUserWithTypeNew(@RequestParam UserTypeEnum type) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate and explain what is this type attribute doing and how to send the request ? Thanks!

Comment: `type` is just a parameter name, it doesn't have anything to do with request mapping. Requests would be `GET /users/copy?type=NEW` or `GET /users/copy?type=OLD`